# update field with a trigger in custom object from pricebookentry

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I have a custom object custom__c with couple of custom fields that needs to determine the price of the product.

- Custom_Child__c is a lookup field that gets the product.
- Price_Book__c is a lookup field that gets the pricebook
- Custom_Child_PB_ID__c is a text field that should the id of the pricebookentry depending which pricebook and product is selected.
- Custom_Child_PB_UnitPRice__c gets the unitprice depending of which pricebook and product is selected depending on the pricebookentryid.

Let me explain more about the custom object:

This object has couple of lookup fields to *products* and *pricebook* i want when i select a product in the lookup field **custom__c** to automatically update the pricebookentryid field **Custom_Child_PB_ID__c** and also update that pricebookentryid price that comes from a pricebook that i already inserted it.

Below is my trigger it works fine except when I want to update the UnitPrice in that custom field **Custom_Child_PB_UnitPRice__c** and the **Custom_Child_PB_ID__c** depending on the Price_Book__c and Custom_Child__c selected.

What I am doing wrong?

```
trigger setPricebookEntryID on custum__c(before update) { 
    Set<Id> setPriceBookId = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,PricebookEntry> mapPriceBookIdToPBE = new Map<Id,PricebookEntry>();
    for (custum__c p : Trigger.new) { 
        if (p.Price_Book__c != null) {
            setPriceBookId.add(p.Price_Book__c);    
        }
    }
    if (!setPriceBookId.isEmpty()) {
        for (PricebookEntry pbe : [SELECT Id, UnitPrice, Pricebook2Id,Product2Id 
                    FROM PricebookEntry
                    WHERE Pricebook2Id IN: setPriceBookId]) {
             mapPriceBookIdToPBE.put(pbe.Pricebook2Id, pbe);
        } 
        for (Custom_c p : Trigger.new) {
            if (mapPriceBookIdToPBE.containskey(p.Price_Book__c) && mapPriceBookIdToPBE.get(p.Price_Book__c).Product2Id == p.Custom_Child__c) {
                p.Custom_Child_PB_ID__c= mapPriceBookIdToPBE.get(p.Price_Book__c).Id;
                p.Custom_Child_PB_UnitPRice__c = mapPriceBookIdToPBE.get(p.Price_Book__c).UnitPrice;
            }
        }             
    }  
}
```

If the field is empty and i am trying to save the record I am getting this.
[image]

Can I make that optional?

Comment: First of all, never perform a query inside for loop. When you will process records in bulk it will surely hit the governor limit.

Comment: Ok thanks Abhishek i will take the query outside of the look.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to update the Custom_Child_PB_UnitPRice__c with the same object record that fired the trigger. Did you mean to update it with the unit price from the PricebookEntry? If so, then you will need to do the following:

```
trigger setPricebookEntryID on custom__c (before insert) { 
   for (custom__c p : Trigger.new) { 
     PricebookEntry pbe = [SELECT Id, UnitPrice FROM 
     PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id = :p.Price_Book__c 
     AND Product2Id = :p.custom_Child__c limit 1];
     p.Custom_Child_PB_ID__c= pbe.Id; 
     p.Custom_Child_PB_UnitPRice__c = pbe.UnitPrice;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian for the help. This works only when I insert a pricebook and not when i don't. I am getting the following error. See update above.

Comment: Have you tried changing your trigger from before insert to before update?

Comment: I did that and i am getting this error:
There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Apex trigger setPricebookEntryID caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: setPricebookEntryID: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: PricebookEntry.Product2Id: Trigger.setPricebookEntryID: line 29, column 1".

Comment: Ok. in your SOQL query add the Product2Id. it is referenced later on but not retrieved in the query. So it should be [SELECT Id, UnitPrice, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id from PricebookEntry .......ect

Comment: Hi Brian, I do what you said I am using the code made by Abhishek as followed and I added the Product2Id and it doesn't get the error, however it doesn't show the price when I populate both the Price_Book__c and custom_Child__c fields :(

Comment: Can you post the updated code you are using in the question section?

Comment: Code updated Brian.

Comment: I see in the updated code you have the trigger firing on object custum__c, but later in the code it shows for (Bundle_Line_Item__c p : Trigger.new). Is Bundle_Line_Item__c the object that the trigger should be firing on?

Comment: yes Bundle_Line_item_c is object. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this issue because the field is empty and it's not returning any number of records

> While a SELECT normally returns an array/list, these statements are using the shorthand syntax that assumes only one row is returned.
>   What’s not obvious is that it also assumes that exactly one row is returned!
>   Refer [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000159853&type=1) for detail explanation around this error
>
> Again, never ever have a SOQL query inside a loop. Loops, especially those iterating over Trigger.new, will easily run 200+ queries and push you across the limit.

You can modify your trigger something like below which will follow all best practices

```
trigger setPricebookEntryID  on custom__c (before insert) {
Set<Id> setPriceBookId = new Set<Id>();
Map<Id,PricebookEntry> mapPriceBookIdToPBE = new Map<Id,PricebookEntry>();
for (custom__c p : Trigger.new) {
    if (p.Price_Book__c != null) {
        setPriceBookId.add(p.Price_Book__c);    
    }   
}

if (!setPriceBookId.isEmpty()) {
    for (PricebookEntry pbe : [SELECT Id, UnitPrice, Pricebook2Id 
                    FROM PricebookEntry
                   WHERE Pricebook2Id IN: setPriceBookId]) {
        mapPriceBookIdToPBE.put(pbe.Pricebook2Id, pbe);
    }   
}

for (custom__c p : Trigger.new) {
    if (mapPriceBookIdToPBE.containskey(p.Price_Book__c) && mapPriceBookIdToPBE.get(p.Price_Book__c).Product2Id == p.custom_Child__c) {
        p.Custom_Child_PB_ID__c= mapPriceBookIdToPBE.get(p.Price_Book__c).Id;
        p.Custom_Child_PB_UnitPRice__c = mapPriceBookIdToPBE.get(p.Price_Book__c).UnitPrice;
    }
}                                                                           }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Abhishek I really appreciate it but this doesn't return the price somehow to my field Custom_Child_PB_UnitPRice__c. Something is missing I can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you facing error while an assignment? Also, debug the value of  mapPriceBookIdToPBE.get(p.Price_Book__c).UnitPrice

Comment: i am kinda getting the exact same error. Maybe I am not doing something right.